# Is justifying communal violence not illegal?

Tags: india, freedom-of-speech, is-x-legal, indian-penal-code

India, unfortunately, has a history of communal violences mostly between two largest religious communities.

Violence due to separatism, casteism, terrorism etc also have similar histories.

There are many prejudices and biases which make *many people* justify such violent acts by not condemning them and saying thinks like —

> - *They [other community] also did similar thing that time*
> - *They're against the nation*
> - *They need to be punished*
> - *They are invaders*
>
> And other similar remarks

**Isn't this (justification of any violence) illegal in India?**

Answer (score 3):

[Art. 19](https://indiankanoon.org/doc/1218090/) of the Indian Constitution states that

> (1) All citizens shall have the right (a) to freedom of speech and
> expression...

from which is follows that you may advance any argument that you want in support of an idea. The courts have never questioned this. There is a potential grey area regarding verbal acts that cause the use of violence, but in terms of presenting reasons that such-and-such acts are good (or bad), that form of expression is absolutely protected. The grey area comes from clause 2:

> Nothing in sub clause (a) of clause (1) shall affect the operation
> of any existing law, or prevent the State from making any law, in so
> far as such law imposes reasonable restrictions on the exercise of the
> right conferred by the said sub clause in the interests of the
> sovereignty and integrity of India, the security of the State,
> friendly relations with foreign States, public order, decency or
> morality or in relation to contempt of court, defamation or incitement
> to an offence

whereby a law against inciting to violence might pass constitutional muster. "Justification" of an action is very different from "inciting" to do an act.